# How to remove rows when the sum of two values equals zero

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm struggling on how can I remove values from a column that are different only on the sign. For example:

```
+---------+----------+----------+
| Company | Total    | ID       |
+---------+----------+----------+
| BFG     |       -13|         1|
| AAA     |        11|         2|
| CCC     |         5|         3|
| BFG     |        13|         4|
| AAA     |       -11|         5|
| AAA     |       -11|         6|
| CCC     |         7|         7|
| CCC     |        -7|         8|
+---------+----------+----------+


-- Desired result, as something like
+---------+----------+----------+
| Company | Debt     | ID       |
+---------+----------+----------+
| CCC     |         5|         3|
| AAA     |       -11|         6|
+---------+----------+----------+
```

Note that the order of the removing don't matter (case of ID 2, 5 and 6).

Any hint on how can I do that?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I'm using SQL Server

Comment: Why did you remove ID 5 and not ID 6?

Comment: Your output seems quite incomplete, and fails to explain why (for example) for `AAA` only the row (-11, 6) should come up (and not any other row with absolute value 11 for the total).

Comment: @TheImpaler the order of the removing don't matter. Sorry for don't explicit, I edited the question

Comment: `MIN(ID) ... GROUP BY Company, ABS(Total)` could do if you don't care about the ID, or indeed the sign of the total (in which case we may as well pick the first one arbitrarily).

Comment: @DaleK, I tried to remove all the the equal values, using ABS(Total), but when I used this approach I deleted all the values. But if I have 3 values (like `AAA`, I need to keep one of values)

Comment: @JeroenMostert, in this case I'd remove all the `AAA` values. But I should remove only the items that SUM would equal zeros.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, If I used this approach, all the `AAA` would be removed?

Comment: Your actual desired result as explained in the comment is an entirely different question than what your title states, so it should not be surprising there's some confusion. It has nothing to do with the sign as such, but whether the ledger balances, and if not you want to see the rows that aren't balanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pair positive numbers with negative ones, one by one. Then remove all the matches.

For example:

```
with
p as (select *, row_number() over(partition by total order by id) as rn from t where total > 0),
n as (select *, row_number() over(partition by total order by id) as rn from t where total < 0),
m as (
  select p.id as pid, n.id as nid
  from p
  join n on -n.total = p.total and n.rn = p.rn
)
delete from t
where id in (select pid from m)
   or id in (select nid from m)
```

Result:

```
 company  total  id 
 -------- ------ -- 
 CCC      5      3  
 AAA      -11    6
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2eec9725f659228ad5834d76167bf47c).

Comment: I think this is on the right track, only deleting matching pairs of debits and credits. What's missing is adding a match for company in the CTE p & n partitions and the m join condition.

Comment: @TN "What's missing is adding a match for company" -- I would guess you are right, but the question doesn't spell it.

Comment: For comparison with the above, this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d03331f2d2aab9e0b33c257cc3e0037b) modifies the above solution to segregate by company and shows results with and without the change. Extra rows were added to the test data to highlight the difference.

Answer (score 0):

After considering what @Jeroen Mostert mentioned in the comments I had another bash at finding a solution using a windowed partition, does the following work for you?

```
with Id as (
    select Max(Id) Id from (
      select *, Abs(Sum(total) over(partition by company, Abs(total))) tot
      from t
    )t
    where tot > 0
    group by company
)
select *
from id join t on Id.id = t.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
Declare @testTable table (Company varchar(10), Total int, ID int)
 Insert Into @testTable (Company, Total, ID)
 Values ('BFG', -13, 1)
      , ('AAA',  11, 2)
      , ('CCC',   5, 3)
      , ('BFG',  13, 4)
      , ('AAA', -11, 5)
      , ('AAA', -11, 6)
      , ('CCC',   7, 7)
      , ('CCC',  -7, 8)
      , ('DDD', -10, 9)
      , ('DDD',  10, 10)
      , ('DDD',  10, 11);

   With groupedRows
     As (
 Select *
      , rn = row_number() Over(Partition By tt.Company, tt.Total Order By tt.ID)
   From @testTable tt
        )
 Select P.Company
      , P.Total
      , P.ID
   From groupedRows             p
   Left Join groupedRows        n On n.rn = p.rn And -n.Total = p.Total
  Where n.rn Is Null;
```